# In mercurial, is there a way to recover from a deleted 00changelog.d?

Tags: mercurial

00changelog.d got deleted accidentally.

Is there a way to recover from this?

Or recover the changes made since the last push?

Comment: Theoretically yes, the first recommendation I would give is making a backup of your repository directory before starting anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is technically possible, though with some information loss as the 00changelog.d file contain information such as the changeset author, the date of the commit, the commit message, and the named branch of the changeset. That said, it is possible to reconstruct the data to a high degree of certainty based on parent information in the `00manifest.{d,i}`.

The data in the `00changelog.d` is part of the changeset's hash, and as such it is important that the data that is shared with an upstream repository is exactly the same, so in order to reconstruct the changelog you need a clone of your upstream repository (what was local only we have some leeway on).

In short, preparation before we begin:

- A clone of the upstream repository (let's assume it's in `./upstream/`)
- A backup of your local repository (let's assume it's in `./local-backup/`)
- Your local repository (let's assume it's in `./local/`)
- `rm ./local/.hg/store/00changelog.*` to start from a fresh slate

Next you need the following Mercurial extension I wrote for the occasion:

```py
import os
import weakref

from mercurial.commands import command
from mercurial import scmutil, changelog, error, node

@command('reconstruct', [], '<path to 00changelog.i>')
def reconstruct(ui, repo, changelog_index):
    'reconstructs repository from upstream changelog if local changelog has been deleted'
    other_opener = scmutil.vfs(os.path.dirname(changelog_index),
                               expandpath=True,
                               realpath=True)
    upstream_changelog = changelog.changelog(other_opener)
    local_manifest = repo.manifest
    local_changelog = repo.changelog

    if len(local_changelog) != 0:
        raise error.Abort('not running on repository with actual changelog data')

    local_manifest_nodes = {local_manifest.node(rev): rev for rev in local_manifest}
    reconstructed_manifests = set()
    reconstructed_manifests_map = {}

    lock = repo.lock()
    try:
        tr = repo.transaction('reconstruct')
        trp = weakref.proxy(tr)

        for rev in upstream_changelog:
            data = upstream_changelog.read(upstream_changelog.node(rev))
            prevs = upstream_changelog.parentrevs(rev)
            p1 = node.nullid if prevs[0] == -1 else upstream_changelog.node(prevs[0])
            p2 = node.nullid if prevs[1] == -1 else upstream_changelog.node(prevs[1])
            if data[0] in local_manifest_nodes:
                n = local_changelog.add(data[0], data[3], data[4],
                                       trp, p1, p2,
                                       data[1], data[2], data[5])
                reconstructed_manifests.add(data[0])
                reconstructed_manifests_map[data[0]] = n

        missing_manifests = sorted(
                ((n, r) for n, r in local_manifest_nodes.iteritems()
                        if n not in reconstructed_manifests),
                key=lambda (x,y): y)

        for n, rev in missing_manifests:
            p1, p2 = local_manifest.parents(n)
            p1 = node.nullid if p1 == node.nullid else reconstructed_manifests_map[p1]
            p2 = node.nullid if p2 == node.nullid else reconstructed_manifests_map[p2]

            n2 = local_changelog.add(n, '', 'missing', trp, p1, p2, 'user')
            reconstructed_manifests_map[n] = n2
        tr.close()
    finally:
        if tr:
            tr.release()
        lock.release()
```

Place this file in `./reconstruct.py`. Now we're able to revive the changes:

- `cd local`
- `hg --config extensions.reconstruct=../reconstruct.py reconstruct ../upstream/.hg/store/00changelog.i`
- wait for a while (there's no progress)

All changes that were local only will have completely bogus changelog information, but this can be fixed up manually using either the `histedit` or `mq` extensions.

Note that the extension above makes a few simplifying assumptions: the manifest corresponds 1:1 to your changelog. Since you only deleted your `00changelog.d` and not your `00changelog.i` it would be possible to use the more accurate parent information from `00changelog.i` but that would require substantially more code.

Also note that the extension above uses somewhat recent Python features, so your Mercurial will need to be based on Python 2.7.